# Why did Midori become Seiji's right hand?

Tags: midori-days

In [Midori Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_Days), Seiji woke up one morning to find his right hand to be Midori. Why is this so? Is it some kind of a curse? Was it explained in the manga or anime why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's explained in the manga but it's sort of like a [Pygmalion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_%28mythology%29) type of story. Seiji can't get a girlfriend because he's got a reputation as a tough guy and most girls are afraid of him, eventhough he's sort of got a noble quality about it all. So he wishes that he had a girlfriend and it just so happened that a Midori from another school likes him. So like Aphrodite did in the Pygmalion myth, his wish is granted through some divine/magical/freak-of-nature event where Midori's consciousness and likeness was transfered to Seiji's right hand.

There's extra meaning here because, being someone who (according to himself) will never find a girlfriend, the only "girlfriend" he'll have is "his right hand", a euphemism turned to reality.

> “Three years high school, and the rest of my life for that matter are gonna end with no girlfriend but my right hand! I can’t take it anymore!”

Additionally, he has a reputation for having a "Demon right hand" through his fighting prowess, and in probably the greatest possible contrast, his "Demon right hand" is turned into Midori (美鳥 *beautiful bird*). This essentially takes away his ability to punch with his right hand and forces him to change as a person.

Comment: Does Midori mean "green" too?

Comment: Midori can mean "green" but that is written as 緑 (I think), which is different than the midori from the title of the show: 美鳥

Comment: I asked since her hair was green :-)

Comment: @aitchnyu I wouldn't be surprised if that had something to do with it